# About stationary and wide-sense stationary processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stationary-processes

I have just started with stochastical calculus, and I need some help with a pair of problems:

$\bullet$If $X(t)$ is a mean square differentiable wide-sense stationary stochastical process then the processes $X(t)$ and $X' (t)$ are orthogonal.

$\bullet$If $X(t)$ is a twice mean square differentiable, stationary and Gaussian stochastical process, such that
$E[X(t)] = 0$, then  $X(t)$ is independent of $X' (t)$ but not independent of
$X''(t)$

I was given the hint that I should use the formula $\Gamma_{X^{(n)},X^{(m)}}(t,s)=(-1)^m\frac{d^{(n+m)}\Gamma_X(\tau)}{d\tau^{(n+m)}}$, where $\tau=t-s$, but I can't get anything from it.
I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Right you have "just started" but surely you tried or you know *some* approaches, no?

Comment: I just edited the post with it, thanks.

Comment: Then explain what is $\Gamma$, then why the formula holds, then what YOU think could be an approach to the problem (the first item being rather simple to solve once one writes the conclusion and the hypothesis on a same slip of paper, I am nearly sure you did not)...

Comment: With $\Gamma$ I was denoting the covariance. I know that formula holds, because we proved it in class. And I think it would be useful for the exercise because checking orthogonality of two processes is the same as checking if $\Gamma_{X,Y}(t,s)=0$.
What I can't see is why, when I put $X$ and $X'$ in the formula, the right side has to be zero, that is, why $\Gamma_X(\tau)$ has to be constant.
About the second part, I don't know how to start. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

Hint for the first point: For every $t$, consider $m(t)=E[X(t)]$, $n(t)=E[X'(t)]$, $f(t)=E[(X(t)-m(t))^2]$ and $g(t)=E[(X(t)-m(t))(X'(t)-n(t))]$. One knows that the function $m$ and $f$ are constant, and one tries to show that $g(t)=0$. One is also advised to use some derivative of some sort.

Thus, one could start by showing that $n(t)=0$ for every $t$, then express $g(t)$ as a derivative of something involving all the rest...

Comment: How do you know $f(t)$ is constant?
I know that $E[X(t)]$ is constant for a w-s stationary process, but why it is also constant its variance ($E[(X(t)-m(t))^2]$)?

Comment: Assuming $f(t)$ is constant (which i can't see yet), I have: As $X(t)$ is m-s differentiable, we have $n(t)=E[X'(t)]=\frac{d}{dt}E[X(t)]=m'(t)$ Then: $$\begin{aligned}g(t) &=E[(X(t)-m(t))*(X'(t)-n(t))] = E[(X(t)-m(t))*(X'(t)-m'(t))]\\ &= E[(X(t)-m(t))*(X(t)-m(t))'] = \Gamma_{(X-m(t)),(X-m(t))'}(t)\\ &= -\frac{d}{dt}\Gamma_{X-m(t)}(t) = -\frac{E[(X-m(t))*(X-m(t))]}{dt} = 0,\end{aligned}$$ where the last equality comes from the fact that $f$ is constant. Am I correct?  Can you also give me some tips for the second question? Thanks a lot, Did.

Comment: Anyone can clarify this questions?

Comment: Well,for the first one, I have this:

$g(t)=-\frac{‌​dE[(X-m(t))*(X-m(t))]}{dt}=-E[\frac{d((X-m(t))*(X-m(t)))}{dt}]=-2g(t)$

So $g(t)$ must be zero, which seems to conclude the first part, without using that $f(t)$ is constant. Is it ok?
And for the second part, the same tactic leads me nowhere. Any other indications? Thanks.

Comment: Anyone can confirm if what I did is ok, and give some approach to the second part?